# How to inject the style of Vue components into iframe?

Tags: iframe, webpack, vue.js, loader

How to inject the style of Vue components into the iframe. (for both standard components and async compoents)

I'm making an vue app which is a html5 widget load with js.

In my app, most of js and css are using in iframes, and they rely on the parent window's objects.

Unlike most iframe apps, It dose not load with an url but is made by vue components (just like this forum thread https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-inside-iframe/6419)

I'm using some workarounds such as cssinjs, inject raw css into iframe within js logic. It should split styles to a single out of .vue file in my way.

Is there a proper way to to that?

Some relates:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/pull/146

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-inside-iframe/6419

Comment: "In my app, most of js and css are using in iframes"  That's maybe not the best architectural choice; it kind of defeats the purpose of using a SPA-type framework.

Comment: @Daniel Beck Thanks! I should manage multiple SPA projects and vendors may load multiple times for users. Besides, making the auto build scripts is a challenge too... In my opinion, iframe is just a element which can keep its style independent from its parent. It's best to keep them in one app if there are a workaround..